# SQL LIKE clause to match closest record

Tags: mysql

I am running this SQL Query to match records against data in a database:

```
SELECT * from billing_match_table WHERE 'Exchange Mailbox plus Outlook' LIKE CONCAT(description, '%');
```

so in the table, there are two rows with descriptions of:

```
Exchange Mailbox

Exchange Mailbox plus Outlook
```

So running this Query will return both records but i want to be able to match the closest record

the reason i use the `CONCAT` this way is because i also have records like this:

`Non-Geographic Number 0843123456` which needs to match `Non-Geographic Number 0843`

and

`Non-Geographic Number 0845123456` which needs to match `Non-Geographic Number 0845`

so how can i match these to the closest record in the database and not just the first row returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the "closest" records would have the longest description that matches the constant string.  If so:

```
SELECT *
FROM billing_match_table
WHERE 'Exchange Mailbox plus Outlook' LIKE CONCAT(description, '%')
ORDER BY length(description) desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: i guess it depends if its the shortest or longest... because Exchange Mailbox plus Outlook needs to match exactly that (longest), and Non-Geographic Number 0843123456 needs to match Non-Geographic Number 0843 (shortest)

Comment: saying that, if i do order bu length(description) desc that would work fine for everything wouldn't it?

Comment: @Charles . . . Your wildcard is at the end of the pattern, so an exactly match is the shortest possible match.  Ordering by the length *asc* is presumably what you mean by "closest".

Comment: @GordonLinoff but this is then going to match Exchange Mailbox plus Outlook to Exchange Mailbox if i used ASC

Comment: @Charles . . . Good morning.  I understand now.  You're right.

Comment: @Charles . . . Yes, it should get the longest description that starts the string you are looking for -- and that should be the closest match.